# extract nodes based on their contents

Tags: json, jq

I have a json file like the following

```
[
  [
    16876,
    {
      "/Type": {
        "N": "/Pages"
      },
      "/Count": {
        "I": 68
      },
      "/Kids": [
        16872,
        16847
      ],
      "/Parent": 16877
    }
  ],
  [
    16877,
    {
      "/Type": {
        "N": "/Pages"
      },
      "/Count": {
        "I": 1604
      },
      "/Kids": [
        16873,
        16874,
        16875,
        16876
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    168, []
  ]
...
]
```

I want to extract the nodes with /Type /Pages. and show /Parent and /Kids along with the first number of each node. In the above example, the output should be something like this, where  is a tab character.

```
16876<TAB>16877<TAB>16872,16847
16877<TAB><TAB>16873,16874,16875,16876
```

How can I perform this extraction?

Answer (score 1):

Use `select` to filter, then compose an array of items, and transform it using `@tsv`:

```bash
jq -r '
  .[] | select(.[1] | objects."/Type".N == "/Pages")
  | [.[0], .[1]."/Parent", (.[1]."/Kids" | join(","))]
  | @tsv
'
```

```
16876   16877   16872,16847
16877       16873,16874,16875,16876
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/E_T-hGImGtA)

EDIT: Using `objects` in the `select` filter allows for the case where the second item is not an object. This implementation silently ignores such a second non-object item. Alternatives could, for instance, consider the first object item found, regardless of its index position. Please specify your requirements.

Comment: I got the following error. "jq: error (at <stdin>:3801150): Cannot index array with string "/Type"" Some objects do not have "/Type". Those objects should be ignored. How to fix the code to accommodate this situation?

Comment: @user119720, please put actually representative sample data in your question.

Comment: The real input is too large to put here. And it is too large to even know what is representative until I try the jq code to see what situations it can not handle. But this error can be induced by removing "/Type" in the current example.

Comment: @user119720 It means that you have entries like this `[ 16876, [ ... ]  ]` instead of `[ 16876, { ... } ]`

Comment: @Fravadona You are right. I edit my post to include this case.

Comment: @user119720 Added an update using `objects` in the `select` filter which allows for the case where the second item is not an object.

Comment: Is this correct? `.[]
 | select(.[1] | type=="object")
 | select(.[1] | objects."/Type".N == "/Pages")
  | [.[1]."/Parent", .[0], (.[1]."/Kids" | join(","))]
  | @tsv` Is it the most succint way of doing it?

Comment: @user119720 Using `objects` in the other `select` already filters just like `select(.[1] | type=="object")` would. Looking at the [source](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L55) reveals that `objects` is defined as `select(type == "object")`.